# How can I pass the multi-line output of a function to a grep?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, aix

I'm new to UNIX and having trouble with what is probably a very simple concept. I would like to take the output of an awk designed to return a single column of data (in this case, it's a couple of lines containing FC WWNs) and use that as a search parameter in a grep the same way I would use a file containing the column.

My first thought was to simply type 
    grep -f awk {'print $3'} myfile myotherfile

Clearly, that didn't work. I know I could do this simply with two commands and an intermediate file (outputting my awk with a > to a new file, and the using the grep -f with it), but I would like to know if there's a way to do this without adding files.

Background: I'm using AIX 5.3 and bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the nifty  `$<` *bash* idiom of bash to replace a file name argument with the output of a specified command.

```
fgrep -f <(awk '{print $3}' myfile) myotherfile
```

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom that appears to work with GNU grep (don't know about AIX grep) is to use `-` as a specification for stdin. So in your case, if I've interpreted the commanded correctly, you'd use:

`awk {'print $3'} myfile | grep -f - myotherfile`

Comment: I tried it and got a "grep: 0652-033 Cannot open -" error. What's this principle called, so I can check the AIX manual to see if they just changed the character used or something?

Comment: I don't think it's called anything. It isn't even mentioned in the GNU grep `man` or `info` pages. It's just something that a lot of programs support so I thought I'd try it.  You could probably do this with named pipes, but in this context it's basically the same as just outputting to a file in the middle.